# Add file to host web in SharePoint hosted app. Is it possible with Manage permissions?

Tags: 2013, rest, access-denied, app, sharepoint-hosted-app

I wonder is it possible to add a file from a SharePoint hosted App to host web without setting Full permission for the Web?

```
function uploadFile(data) {            
var url = appUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Style Library')/files/add(url='a.txt',overwrite=true)?@target='" + hostUrl + "'";
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appUrl.toLowerCase());

executor.executeAsync(
    {
        url: url.toLowerCase(),
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (result) {    
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function (result, errorCode, errorMessage) {
            console.log(errorMessage);  
        }
    }
);}
```

When I run it with **Manage** permission on Web I get **403 Access Denied**. When change to **Full** - **200 OK**. Any ideas how to overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving `Full Control` permissions on Web give `Full Control` permissions on the library only.